# Set Initial value to vue.js model which is directly available in HTML

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have my code in PHP, I do have some variable suppose

```
$checked = true;
```

and I am writing something like this

```
<input v-model="subscribed" type="checkbox" <?= ($checked ? 'checked' : '') ?>  />
```

now in my vue js file how do I populate my model with this checked data so

`subscribed`  has value of true or false. **(I don't intend to assign value to js directly by PHP code I need to set it inside/in input it self not anywhere else)**

please check code snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
     <label>
       <input id='sub' v-model="subscribed" @click="printState" type="checkbox" checked />
       Subscription
     </label>
  </div>
  <script>  
   new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: function() {
        return {
          subscribed: false,
          // subscribed: sub.checked
          // ^ this works but i dont want to add everytime id and get its value manually
        }
      },
      created: function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          console.log('Checkbox is having its initial value true/checked');
          console.log(self.subscribed);
        }, 1000)
      },
      methods: {
        printState: function(){
           console.log(this.subscribed)
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

you can see now **I have to add model variable in data `subscribed` but then I also need to provide its value and if I provide its value then it will override its actual value** ( so to make it work I am settings it value initially from the DOM element it self {`sub.checked` sub is dom element fetched by dom.getelembyid... } but I don't like that way as there will be much more elements (text|select|radio) etc ..)

so is there any way (elegant way) that `subscribed` will pick its value automatically from the input it self.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Vue` really isn't designed to init from the `HTML`, however, one approach is to use a directive to `init` the values. This is loosely based around the same idea as Angular's [`ng-init`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

```
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
});
```

That essentially takes the binding argument, which is the name after the colon (see below) and sets it to the given value on the Vue instance, which you can then use as:

```
<input v-model="subscribed" type="checkbox" v-init:subscribed="<?=($checked) ? 'true' : 'false'?>"  />
```

A few caveats with that though, firstly you still need to declare your data properties upfront, it won't dynamically inject them, secondly everything get evaluated as `JavaScript`, so if you want to init with a string it needs to be wrapped in single quotes and finally it won't understand `camelCase`, so if you want to set `camelCase` data properties you will need to write a `kebab-case` to `camelCase` conversion in the directive.

Here's your updated snippet in a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/evnctym1/

Comment: yes, we can declare it upfront but at least we can pass default value in clean way, and we can manage case np here, thanks.

Comment: thanks, but in case, data properties is array, this solution not resolve.

Answer (score 24):

This is not in the spirit of Vue, as you should have logic outside the template when feasible, but here's a clever workaround that should work in most situations

```
<input 
  v-model="foobar"
  :run="!foobar ? foobar = 1 : true"
/>
```

`:run` isn't a special attribute, it's completely arbitrary. I use it to define the value of what I'm v-modeling.

In my case, this was useful because I needed to v-model on an index of an array where the index doesn't exist yet. The template is creating the index it v-models on. I do advise against the above workaround and suggest testing throughly if you use it for potential side effects, but it will let you init a value inline in the template.

Comment: This is brilliant. The best part is I can declare arbitrary scoped variables using this like :run="doesntexists = 1" without declaring them in `data`

Comment: great solution. In my case I had a nested object, I use it like
`:run="!dt.object ? dt.object.nested = {some_data: ''} : true"
v-model='dt.object.nested'`

Comment: great solution. in my case I'm using a database row column as object storage.  Saves me from having to create a one-to-many cross reference table for a multiple select. But i need a way to ensure the v-model is a reactive array.
`<q-select  outlined  label="Categories (Multiple Select)" v-model="row.Categories" :options="['Category 1','Category 2','Category 3','Category 4','Category 5']" multiple :runonload="row.Categories=!Array.isArrayrow.Categories)?[]:row.Categories">`

Answer (score 2):

Here's some possible concepts you might find useful when binding your backend data with Vue.

#### 0. Build a REST API and use it

Preferred approach but sometimes this is not possible. For example, if you don't have full control over the backend code.

#### 1. You could assign global variables

To get your data inside Vue context with PHP/HTML:

```
<script>
var myDataFromPhp = {
  stringExample: '<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>',
  objectExample: JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode(["Hello again" => "Greetings from Mars!"]); ?>'),
}
</script>
```

In Vue:

```
data: {
  someString: window.myDataFromPhp && window.myDataFromPhp.stringExample? window.myDataFromPhp.stringExample : '',
  someObject: window.myDataFromPhp && window.myDataFromPhp.objectExample? window.myDataFromPhp.objectExample : {},
},
```

Maybe just stuff all data in one object at the PHP side to make it prettier. You could also use variable naming that says it's read only and meant to be static: `var _OBJECT_EXAMPLE = ...`

---

#### 2. If you don't feel like exposing a global variable inside a `<script>` tag

When binding form data to Vue, the following has worked for me when initialising Vue app in specific state. This is useful if you just have one little thing you need to bind.

Inside your Vue app's scope:

```
<input name="someInputData" type="hidden" :value="someInputData = 'Heya!'">
```

Then declare data in Vue app:

```
data: {
  someInputData: undefined, // NOTE: This one is initialised in template element input[name="someInputData"]
},
```

I'm not sure if this has any async side effects. Use with caution and test.

---

#### 3. Use vanilla JS:

In HTML:

```
data: {
  someInputData: document.getElementById('my-hidden-input')? document.getElementById('my-hidden-input').value : undefined, 
}
```

Just make sure there's only unique DOM elements or your data will be all wrong ...

Answer (score 1):

An improvement based on @craig_h answer

```js
Vue.directive('init', {
  bind (el, binding, vnode) {
    vnode.context[binding.arg] = binding.value;
  }
})
```

```js
Vue.new({
  data: {
     name: undefined,
  }
}
```

```html
<input v-model="name" v-init:name="'Seballot'" />
```

And to directly used the standard `value` attribute, and make it works with checkboxes and radio buttons I made this hacky code

```js
// Run this method just before initializing your Vue instance
function initVModels() {
  for(let el of document.querySelectorAll('[v-model]')) {
    let value = null
    switch (el.getAttribute('type')) {
      case "checkbox": 
        value = $(this).prop('checked'); break
      case "radio": 
        let checkedRadio = document.querySelector(`[name="${el.getAttribute('name')}"]:checked`); 
        value = checkedRadio ? `'${checkedRadio.value}'` : null
        break
      default: 
        value = el.value ? el.value : el.getAttribute('value') 
        if (value) value = `'${value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>').replace(/(')/g, "&apos;")}'`  // line breaks and single quote breaks the html syntax, so replacing 
        break
    }
    if (value) el.setAttribute(`v-init:${el.getAttribute('v-model')}`, value)
  }
}
```

Then you can simply use

```html
<!-- Text Input -->
<input v-model="testString" value="Seballot" />

<!-- Select -->
<select v-model="testSelect">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar" selected>Bar</option>
</select>

<!-- Checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" v-model="testBoolean" checked />

<!-- Radio Input -->
<input type="radio" id="foo" name="testRadio" value="foo" checked>
<label for="foo">Foo</label>
<input type="radio" id="bar" name="testRadio" value="bat">
<label for="bar">Bar</label>
```

And the data will be initialized as follow

```js
testString: "Seballot"
testSelect: "bar"
testBoolean: true
testRadio: "foo"
```

Comment: it worked for me like that `v-model="name" v-init="name ='Hello'" `

Answer (score -2):

Directive `v-model` ignores the initial state state of inputs. So, you can't set the `value`, `checked` or `selected` on any form elements. As source of truth are always treated the Vue instance data. So, you should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the `data` option of the particular component.

Comment: yes, you are very correct about it, but is there any way that what i said is possible. to set initial value .. either you need to write inline js using your code then you assign that variable to data, OR you can fire ajax request then assign incoming data, but anything else we can do about it , lot of time i have my data already set in form's input (HTML is already there) but i need to add extra code just to set initial state (can we do anything else apart from this)

Comment: There are some "how to set the initial values" approaches. Look for them. In combination with PHP, favorite approach is setting the `window.__init__` structure. Mainly do not use the inline JS for these purposes.

Comment: yes i see, I know about it but <? = 'window.__init__='  . json_encode($data) . ';'  ?> is same thing like inline , thanks for help but this not what i am looking, doing same this for 3 years, but i thought there will be some other way. anyways thanks for help