# Why is my MVC RazorView textarea being cleared when I bind it to VueJS v-model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, model-view-controller, vuejs2

Here's my cshtml:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content, new { @class="form-control", @style = "max-width:800px", @v_model = "content" })
```

And here's my VueJs...

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app-pagecontent-edit',
    data: {
        editorType: 'plainText',
        content: ''
    },
    methods: {
    }
})
```

The problem is that the data initially populated by the MVC viewmodel isn't showing. It's being cleared out on load. What's going on here? I need two-way binding between MVC and VueJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in Vue [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage)

> `v-model` will ignore the initial `value`, `checked`, or `selected` attributes found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on the JavaScript side, inside the `data` option of your component.

If your Vue app source code is part of the same MVC view, you can assign the initial value there but I do not recommend it as the result is hard to read and maintain

The only other way is to use some technique that stores the initial value in some other way and initializes the `v-model` when the component is created. You can find some of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47885443/381282) - using custom directive seems like a very clear and elegant solution...

Comment: I'll give you the credit because you gave me a piece of the answer. I ended up finding a way around it.